# Android onSensorChanged not called on some devices

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, tilt-sensor

This code registers an accelerometer listener:

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager)ct.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
```

But on the following devices, the callback `onSensorChanged()` is not fired.

```
samsung_SM-T210_KOT49H_19    
TCT_Vodafone 875_JRO03C_16   
samsung_SM-N9005_KOT49H_19   
samsung_SM-T211_KOT49H_19    
richview_6515_MocorDroid2.3.5_10
```

Are there any workarounds for this?
(I need to know the tilt/inclination angle of the device).

Comment: Any solution? I've meet same problem.